# Can a CodeMirror 'mode' replace tags with colors?

Tags: javascript, mode, codemirror

I want to display an `ansi` document (Unix terminal transcripts with escape codes to apply colors) in `CodeMirror`, but there is no `mode` for that.

I could try to make my own mode, and although it seems quite complicated, I haven't found any mode to use as a template that actually removes certain characters from the original content.

I need to remove the escape characters and use them to mark the start or end of a color.

Is this at all possible? Or does `CodeMirror` by design lack the possibility to do this (remove characters in a `mode`)?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but awkward. A mode won't do this (as you noticed, it doesn't remove characters -- you could style them `display: none`, but that'll cause other problems.

An addon that listens for `"change"` events and uses `markText` [1](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText) to style and hide pieces of the document could work. But making it clever (only updating the parts that change, rather than re-coloring the whole document on every change) requires some complexity.